# isc-dhcp-server doesn't start automatically

Tags: linux, linux-networking, service, upstart, isc-dhcp

Running on Astra Linux 1.3, my dhcp service (isc-dhcp-server) is well-configured now and work as expected with a slight nuance - it works only when it's started, but a system don't run it at startup. Doing `sudo update-rc.d isc-dhcp-server defaults` doesn't help. Another services can be added to (and removed from) autostart this way since this is native to this SysV based system. What I have to do to make it run? Thanks.

P.S.
`uname -a` gives

> 3.2.0-27-generic

Right after reboot, `sudo service --status-all` gives

> [ - ]  isc-dhcp-server

Comment: the `isc-dhcp-server` doesn't like to start if it is configured to serve networks/subnets that it doesn't have an interface on.  Could it be that the dhcpd service is starting (or trying to) before the network cards are active?

Comment: Tried some methods to force it to wait for a network or just put it before network daemon on startup sequence, no effect. It seems it just not started by init.

Comment: `update-rc.d isc-dhcp-server` gives no error. /etc/rc*.d shows it's scripts is placed after wicd's ones (number SNN* is bigger).
And last, it doesn't put any message to syslog that it could if it is started in a wrong environment.

Comment: placed $wicd into required-start section into /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server, no effect

Comment: It seems I need to use cron watchdog to observe isc-dhcp-server or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ivanivan said, daemon didn't start because of all network interfaces were down. So I've decided to call start script again after they start. My system uses wicd as network manager and it can call some scripts when network state changes.

Kind of hack, but it's working. I've placed a script into /etc/wicd/scripts/postconnect :

```
sleep 60
/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start
```

and voila, daemon starts as expected.

Note: `sleep 60` is required since network starts working exactly after 60 seconds after script is called.

Comment: Thanks! Worked even without `sleep` statement.

Answer (score 3):

I use `Ubuntu Server 18.04` and I was facing a similar problem: the `isc-dhcp-server` won't automatically start. For me, it turns out the problem was that the service was disabled; executing `sudo systemctl enable isc-dhcp-server` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the above answers worked for me, so I also did a hack - I edited `/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server` and added a `sleep 20` to the beginning of the `start` command in the script, so changed so it looks like the following:

```
case "$1" in
    start)
        sleep 20         # <--- added this line (without the comment)
        test_config
        log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile "$DHCPD_PID" \
            --exec /usr/sbin/dhcpd -- \
            -q $OPTIONS -cf "$DHCPD_CONF" -pf "$DHCPD_PID" $INTERFACES
        sleep 2

        if check_status -q; then
            log_end_msg 0
        else
            log_failure_msg "check syslog for diagnostics."
            log_end_msg 1
            exit 1
        fi
        ;;
```

Now it works (after an initial delay of 20 seconds of course).

Answer (score 0):

I have the interfaces configured via dhcpcd5, since the isc-dhcp-server fails to start because the interfaces aren't yet configured at boot time I created the `/etc/dhcpcd.exit-hook` file and added this command:

```
/bin/systemctl start isc-dhcp-server
```

An example of commands that can be placed inside this file can be find at this [link.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/dhcpcd#DHCP_static_route(s))
Now isc-dhcp-server starts regularly every time that the system boots!

Answer (score 0):

I get into the same problem.
Solved adding network.target on required.
Notice the `isc-dhcp-server.service` has configured requiring only the network-online.target. I saw a very confusing explanation on `man systemd.special` about this...
So , I just added the option, reloaded the systemd with `systemctl daemon-reload` and rebooted my Linux, start to work fine...

```
# Provides:          isc-dhcp-server
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $network $syslog network.target
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $network $syslog network.target
#
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using sleep, but that is definitely not the right answer.  The required-start "network.target" I tried, but that was not sufficient.  It's clear the $network and network.target (I also tried network-online.target) aren't sufficient, but waiting 20 seconds buys enough time for the interface to actually come up.

I'm on Raspbian 11, fwiw.  I could write something to auto-detect the interface is up, but that seems counter to the spirit of systemd.